# I have a problem with paint(Graphics g) method in paddle moving to left or right

Tags: java

I have a problem with the paddle for moving left and right, here is the code.
the repaint method also doesn't work properly. I have revised the code many times but in no vain.

I don't want to use PaintComponent for now.
I would love to know what is the exact problem in the code.
Appreciate your help.

```java
package com.zharawa;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new GameFrame("Brick Breaker", 800, 700);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.zharawa;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    private String title;
    private int width, height;
    GamePanel gamePanel;
    
    public GameFrame(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(gamePanel);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.zharawa;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private int paddleXdir=350;
    private int paddleYdir=600;
    private int paddleWidth=150;
    private int paddleHeight=10;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {     
        //draw borders
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 785, 5); 
        g.fillRect(0, 5, 5, 655);
        g.fillRect(780, 5, 5, 655);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(5, 655, 775, 5);
         
        //draw ball
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(300, 450, 20, 20);
         
        //draw bricks
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //   g.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 30);
             
        //}
         
        //draw paddle
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(paddleXdir, paddleYdir, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
         
        g.dispose();
     }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            paddleXdir+=25;
        }
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            paddleXdir-=25;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: *I don't want to use PaintComponent* - that is the proper way to do custom painting. Update your code. All you need do is rename the paint() method. How difficult is that? Other changes: 1) Don't use g.dispose(). You should only dispose a Graphics object that you create. You did not create the Graphics object that is passed to the paintComponent() method, so don't dispose it. 2) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`. See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't understand *camickr*'s comment. You need to change the name of method `paint` to `paintComponent`. You also need to call the superclass method. As well you need to add a call to method `repaint()` in your `keyPressed()` method.

I made the necessary changes to your `GamePanel` class. I also added a `main()` method just to make the below code an application that you can run. You can safely remove the `main()` method from the below code.

```java
package com.zharawa;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private int paddleXdir=350;
    private int paddleYdir=600;
    private int paddleWidth=150;
    private int paddleHeight=10;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // CHANGE METHOD NAME (from 'paint')
        super.paintComponent(g); // ADDED THIS LINE
        //draw borders
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 785, 5); 
        g.fillRect(0, 5, 5, 655);
        g.fillRect(780, 5, 5, 655);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(5, 655, 775, 5);
         
        //draw ball
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(300, 450, 20, 20);
         
        //draw bricks
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //   g.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 30);
             
        //}
         
        //draw paddle
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(paddleXdir, paddleYdir, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
         
        g.dispose();
     }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            paddleXdir+=25;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            paddleXdir-=25;
        }
        repaint(); // ADDED THIS LINE
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(800, 700);
            frame.add(new GamePanel());
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

The `actionPerformed()` method will be required when you add animation, i.e. make the "ball" move across the screen. In order to add animation you will need to use a [Swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your keyListener isn't attached to the main panel. Your keyboard events aren't being recorded. This answer only responds to the paddle's immobility:

`GameFrame` class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    private String title;
    private int width, height;
    GamePanel gamePanel;

    public GameFrame(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(gamePanel);
        this.addKeyListener( new CustomActionListener() );
    }

    class CustomActionListener implements KeyListener  {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                gamePanel.moveRight();
            }

            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                gamePanel.moveLeft();

            // Required after any change:
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

`GamePanel` class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private int paddleXdir=350;
    private int paddleYdir=600;
    private int paddleWidth=150;
    private int paddleHeight=10;

    protected void moveRight() {
        paddleXdir+=25;
    }

    protected void moveLeft() {
        paddleXdir-=25;
    }

    public GamePanel() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //draw borders
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 785, 5);
        g.fillRect(0, 5, 5, 655);
        g.fillRect(780, 5, 5, 655);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(5, 655, 775, 5);

        //draw ball
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(300, 450, 20, 20);

        //draw bricks
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //   g.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 30);

        //}

        //draw paddle
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(paddleXdir, paddleYdir, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you briefly answer my 4 questions?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the paint(Graphics g) method to painting or other name but all the graphics are gone.
The problem is with the paddle, it has a weird behavior when try to move its direction.

Answer (score 0):

1- I used  `super.paint(g);`
and the problem of updating the paddle fixed, but why I have to use `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` in the GameFrame class?
If I dont use `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` sometimes the paddle move sometimes doesn't. I mean why is it necessary to use this line of code `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` in the GameFrame class while I have this `addKeyListener(this);` line in the GameFrame class?

2- what are the differences between `public void paint(Graphics g)
super.paint(g);`
and
 `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
super.paintComponent(g);`? Because I get the same result for this specific example of mine.

3- Why the background of the game is not black though I have this line `this.setBackground(Color.black);` in GameFrame class?

4- Why only If I remove `super.paint(g);` the background of the game gets its color which is black and then the paddle doesn't get updated properly?

`public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new GameFrame("SnakeGame", 800, 700);
    
   }

}`



    
    `public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
        
        private String title;
        private int width, height;
        GamePanel gamePanel;
        
        
        public GameFrame(String title, int width, int height) {
            this.title = title;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            
            gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            this.setSize(width, height);
            this.setTitle("Brick Breaker");
            this.setBackground(Color.black);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.add(gamePanel);
            this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);
            
        }
    
    }`


    
    `public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
        private int paddleXdir=350;
        private int paddleYdir=600;
        private int paddleWidth=150;
        private int paddleHeight=10;
        
        public GamePanel() {
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);        
            
        }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {     
        super.paint(g);
         
        //draw borders
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
         g.fillRect(0, 0, 785, 5); 
         g.fillRect(0, 5, 5, 655);
         g.fillRect(780, 5, 5, 655);
         g.setColor(Color.red);
         g.fillRect(5, 655, 775, 5);
         
         
         //draw ball
         g.setColor(Color.green);
         g.fillOval(300, 450, 20, 20);
         
         
         //draw bricks
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //   g.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 30);
             
        //}
         
         //draw paddle
         g.setColor(Color.green);
         g.fillRect(paddleXdir, paddleYdir, paddleWidth,      paddleHeight);
                 
     }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        paddleXdir+=25;
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            paddleXdir-=25;
        
        repaint();
            
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        }

        }

</code>`

Comment: Copy paste my response. Then everything you described works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Help Please-------------

1- I used  `super.paint(g);`
and the problem of updating the paddle fixed, but why I have to use `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` in the GameFrame class?
If I dont use `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` sometimes the paddle move sometimes doesn't. I mean why is it necessary to use this line of code `this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);` in the GameFrame class while I have this `addKeyListener(this);` line in the GameFrame class?

2- what are the differences between `public void paint(Graphics g)
super.paint(g);`
and
 `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
super.paintComponent(g);`? Because I get the same result for this specific example of mine.

3- Why the background of the game is not black though I have this line `this.setBackground(Color.black);` in GameFrame class?

4- Why only If I remove `super.paint(g);` the background of the game gets its color which is black and then the paddle doesn't get updated properly?

`public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new GameFrame("SnakeGame", 800, 700);
    
}

}`


`public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    
    private String title;
    private int width, height;
    GamePanel gamePanel;
    
    
    public GameFrame(String title, int width, int height) {
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setTitle("Brick Breaker");
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.add(gamePanel);
        this.addKeyListener(gamePanel);
        
    }

}`



    
    `public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
        private int paddleXdir=350;
        private int paddleYdir=600;
        private int paddleWidth=150;
        private int paddleHeight=10;
        
        public GamePanel() {
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);        
            
        }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {     
        super.paint(g);
         
        //draw borders
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
         g.fillRect(0, 0, 785, 5); 
         g.fillRect(0, 5, 5, 655);
         g.fillRect(780, 5, 5, 655);
         g.setColor(Color.red);
         g.fillRect(5, 655, 775, 5);
         
         
         //draw ball
         g.setColor(Color.green);
         g.fillOval(300, 450, 20, 20);
         
         
         //draw bricks
        // g.setColor(Color.blue);
        // for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        //   g.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 30);
             
        //}
         
         //draw paddle
         g.setColor(Color.green);
         g.fillRect(paddleXdir, paddleYdir, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
                 
     }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        paddleXdir+=25;
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            paddleXdir-=25;
        
        repaint();
            
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    }`